# What we use for new line in asp.net when using with java script

Tags: javascript, asp.net

The following code is working properly but what we do for new line in alert message.

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "a", "<script>alert('Value of a is: '+ "+a+");</script>");
```

Output:

```
value of a is:10
```

(a is a variable)
But I need the following output:

```
value of a is :
10
```

(10 in new line)

Answer (score 2):

`\n` serves as new line in alerts. Try this:

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "a", "alert('Value of a is:\\n" + a + "');", true);
```

Or this

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "a", @"alert('Value of a is:\n" + a + "');", true);
```

Comment: My bad. Forgot escape the \. From C# it should be \\n. Corrected.